# Possible to repeat background image outwards from center?

Tags: css, background, position, background-image, repeat

I'm wondering if this is possible with CSS. I want my background image to begin from an absolute center alignment and tile repeat outwards from there.

[image: Background image to repeat outwards from center]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
background-attachment: fixed
```

See example: http://codepen.io/ryanmclaughlin/pen/3ba02dcabedee91b09cf816d43d148c4

Answer (score 1):

You can use background-position property to center the background and set the repeat value to background, background: url('yourimage') repeat;

Comment: background: url(pattern.png) center center; /* repeat is a default */

Comment: @Sigma Sure, I gave the detailed version ;)

Comment: This doesn't do what I want. It vertically centers the image to the top of the screen. I want the background-image to always be centered horizontally and vertically in the middle of the element (whether a div or the body). See: http://codepen.io/ryanmclaughlin/pen/3ba02dcabedee91b09cf816d43d148c4

Answer (score 0):

```
#pattern{
    background: url('pattern.jpg') center center;
    /* other stuff here */
}
```